# How to Programmatically Create Adobe Flash Slideshow?

Tags: python, flash

I want to take a group of pictures that I have and create a slideshow to embed on Facebook.  Since Facebook allows the embedding of .swf files via their OpenGraph api, I would like to programmatically create a .swf slideshow from my group of pictures.  Preferably this would be done using Python, but I'm open to whatever works.

Does anybody know of any library that supports this?

Comment: Check the ming https://github.com/libming/libming

Comment: https://github.com/chrippa/python-flashmedia

Comment: @Ajay thank you for the suggestions, however `python-flashmedia` only manages existing flash files, rather than creating new ones.  `libming` provides almost no documentation, isn't actively maintained, and all of the links on their site to examples or documentation are broken. Surely there is a current library for this that somebody knows about?

Answer (score -1):

I think Adobe Flash is the easiest solution for what you're trying to do. You don't need a library to create a .swf slideshow, as this is a basic task, you don't have to be an expert. There are tons of tutorials out there that show you how to create a slideshow in Adobe Flash. For example:

http://multimedia.journalism.berkeley.edu/tutorials/flash-intro/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5yjvBDgB0NA

Hope this helps!

Comment: I want to create a flash slideshow *programmatically*; that is, without the GUI of Adobe Flash.

Comment: Ok, sorry, it wasn't clear from the question that you wouldn't want to use Adobe Flash. I  thought first of the final result, which should be a .swf file.  Flash still remains the most straight forward and easiest solution, though.